# ActiveRecord: How to find Postgres rows with empty array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model created with this migration:

```
create table :some_table do |t|
  t.string :list, array: true, default: []
end
```

I would like to find the record whose "list" array is empty. I tried with this:

```
SomeTable.where(list: [])
```

but it returns `nil` and I have records with the list emtpy.

Comment: try `SomeTable.where(list: {})`

Comment: may you like to study more about it https://dockyard.com/blog/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support

Comment: Can you put this through an answer? I will give you karma then. Ah, and it's `where(list: '{}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SomeTable.where(list: '{}')
```

[Reference list datatype](https://dockyard.com/blog/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support)